# Final variable printing in java

Tags: java, final

```
final int a=5;
System.out.println(a+1)
```

prints 6 whereas `System.out.println(a++)` or `a=a+1` and then `s.o.p(a)` would give error.

Why would it print 6 when final values cant be changed?

Comment: you can't change the value of a final variable.

Answer (score 1):

Both `a++` and `a=a+1` assign a new value to `a`.

`a+1` does not: it just evaluates to 1 more than the value in `a`.

Evaluating the statements:

```
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(a+1);
System.out.println(a);
```

will show that the value of `a` is the same before and after. Doing the same with `a++` or `a=a+1` in the middle statement (obviously making `a` non-final first) will show that `a` is changed.

This should be no more surprising than `System.out.println(5+1)` printing 6, whilst leaving the values of `5` and `1` unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Because you never modify `a` in your example. You print the result of `a+1`. If you print a afterwards you'll see that it is still `5`.

It is basically

```
int a = 5;
int b = a+1;
System.out.println(b); // prints 6
System.out.println(a); // still prints 5
```